# Select todo los checkbox pero con una condiccion

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código donde selecciono todo los checkbox de  una tabla.

Aqui mi tabla

```
<div class="table-responsive row">
  <table id="TablaCargaOP" class="table table-bordered ">
      <thead>
          <tr class="bg-primary" id="EncabCargaOP">
              <th width="5%">OP</th>
              <th width="5%">Item</th>
              <th width="18%">CodPza</th>
              <th width="20%">Desc.</th>
              <th width="5%">Cant.</th>
              <th width="8%">Medidas.</th>
              <th class="text-center" width="12%">Nivel</th>
              <th width="8%">Pedido</th>
              <th width="5%">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" onchange="checkAll(this)" id="selectAll">
                    <label class="form-check-label"for="selectAll">  <i class="fa fa-arrows-v" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
                </div>
                </th>

          </tr>
      </thead>
  </table>

</div>
```

Metodo para seleccionar todo los checkbox.Este método lo saque de aquí [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/7Dqqf/82/)

```
<script>
function checkAll(ele) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var celdas = $('#tableDespacho tbody > tr').find('td');
    var status = $(celdas[7]).html();

    if (ele.checked) {

        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                checkboxes[i].checked = true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            console.log(i)
            if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                checkboxes[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Lo que deseo es poder agregar una condiccion si el estado se encuentra `SI` este no se marque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas es algo como esto:

```js
function checkAll(ele) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var celdas = $('#TablaCargaOP tbody > tr');
    
    if (ele.checked) {
        for (var i = 1; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            var status = $(celdas[i - 1]).find('td').eq(7).html();            
            if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox' && status == 'SI') {
                checkboxes[i].checked = true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {            
            if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                checkboxes[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive row">
  <table id="TablaCargaOP" class="table table-bordered ">
      <thead>
          <tr class="bg-primary" id="EncabCargaOP">
              <th width="5%">OP</th>
              <th width="5%">Item</th>
              <th width="18%">CodPza</th>
              <th width="20%">Desc.</th>
              <th width="5%">Cant.</th>
              <th width="8%">Medidas.</th>
              <th class="text-center" width="12%">Nivel</th>
              <th width="8%">Pedido</th>
              <th width="5%">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" onchange="checkAll(this)" id="selectAll">
                    <label class="form-check-label"for="selectAll">  <i class="fa fa-arrows-v" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
                </div>
                </th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="bg-primary" id="EncabCargaOP">
              <td width="5%">OP</td>
              <td width="5%">Item</td>
              <td width="18%">CodPza</td>
              <td width="20%">Desc.</td>
              <td width="5%">Cant.</td>
              <td width="8%">Medidas.</td>
              <td class="text-center" width="12%">Nivel</td>
              <td width="8%">SI</td>
              <td width="5%">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">                    
                </div>
                </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="bg-primary" id="EncabCargaOP">
              <td width="5%">OP</td>
              <td width="5%">Item</td>
              <td width="18%">CodPza</td>
              <td width="20%">Desc.</td>
              <td width="5%">Cant.</td>
              <td width="8%">Medidas.</td>
              <td class="text-center" width="12%">Nivel</td>
              <td width="8%">NO</td>
              <td width="5%">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">                    
                </div>
                </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```